# the tag was existing in the HTML code but cannot reach by xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

cannot locate @id="todds from XPath, but the tag was existing in the HTML code

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")
time.sleep(5)

lines = ['; '.join([j.text for j in i.find_elements_by_xpath('./td/div | ./td/span/span | ./td/span[not(span)]') if j.text]) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="todds"]/tr') if i.text]

for line in lines:
print line

driver.close()
```

Comment: let it load https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: dear, i added time.sleep(5) but it seem not working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element with `id="todds"` is not a `table` or `tbody` so it doesn't have `tr` children

Try below instead

```
lines = ['; '.join([j.text for j in i.find_elements_by_class_name('couponRow') if j.text]) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="todds"]//div[@class="couponTable"]') if i.text]

for line in lines:
    print line
```